# I have trouble getting a function to execute correctly before template loading

Tags: meteor

I believe the issue is with the routing, but I may be wrong here.

I have an issue where a function that I call via Iron Router sometimes doesn't fully finish making necessary computations before the template renders and the page is filled with n/a's and NaNs (because of the calculations not finishing before the template loads or renders). So what happens is after the user logs in, he/she uploads data via external file. This data is then stystematically added to an existing MongoDB collection then calculations are being made by function `computeValues()`.

My problem, as I've stated above, is that there are times where the `computeValues()` function doesn't completely finish making necessary calculations, but the template renders anyway. When I refresh this page, the process works as it's supposed to. It's only when I'm routed from one page to this particular template/page (called `mainPage`) when this issue exists. Then, there are other instances where it works like it's supposed to and the template doesn't render before the function executes and computers the data completely.

Here is the particular code for the Iron Router:

```
Router.route("/analyze/main", {name: "main",
subscriptions: function(){
  return Meteor.subscribe("data");
},
onBeforeAction: function(){
  if(! Meteor.user()){
    this.layout("accessDenied");
  } else{
    this.next();
}},
action: function(){
this.wait(computeValues());
if(this.ready()){
  this.layout("mainPage");
} else{
  this.layout("loading");
}
}});
```

Here is what I added to the template's onRendered() function:

```
Template.mainPage.onRendered(function(){
  computeValues();
});
```

Adding or removing the onRendered part for the template makes no reason. The problems still persist from time to time. I just can't figure out what's causing this or how to fix it.

The particular function that does all the calculations, `computeValues()`, is located in the lib folder due to the need to expedite the loading process and have access to global variables immediately. I can't post the code because it's over 3000 lines long. But the extensiveness of this function does not explain why it works 20% of the time when routed, and not working 80% of the time, all while working 100% of the time being on the `mainPage` template and refreshing for reload.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IR to *waitOn* one or more subscriptions but it's not quite as well suited to waiting on set of computations.

Firstly I would move `computeValues()` to `Template.mainPage.onCreated` rather than `onRendered`

Secondly I would set a session variable to false when starting the computation and to true when finished and show a spinner in the template until it becomes true.

Comment: I tried creating Session variables, one at the start of the function to indicate the initialization and one at the end of the function to indicate completion, but all I see for the most part is the spinner spinning forever. I feel as though the computeValues() function is even starting for it to act this way.

Comment: Is the session variable getting correctly set at the end of the computations?

Comment: Well, I added 2 sessions. One for initiation and what when the function finishes. The router's action block looks like this: `action: function(){
if(Session.get("initiation")){
  this.layout("loading");
  if(Session.get("initiationComplete")){
    this.layout("mainPage");
  }
}`

Comment: IMO you'd be better off with a single one. Just toggle it at start and end.

Comment: That's what I did the first time, but the page was loading the entire time and not progressing. The second session variable towards the end of the function probably isn't triggering correctly.

Comment: I think there's more to this problem than time.

Comment: It definitely is with my configuration of Iron Router. When I'm on `mainPage` and refresh, the load order is correct 100% of the time and no issue occurs. It's just when I'm routed from x page to the `mainPage` is when the template renders before the function is finished computing the necessary data required for the template. I'll just try different things to see what sticks and what doesn't.

Comment: I just want to update that I believe I have fixed the issue. It hasn't failed after I tried the routing for at least 30 times. The only change I made is placed the subscription in the `waitOn` block instead of the `subscriptions` block and I added console.log statements along every part of the routing process. I'm not sure how these console log statements are allowing the process to function normally. Maybe gives the router enough time to subscribe to the complete data via the `waitOn` block? Not sure, but it's working.

Comment: `waitOn` is where you normally want to put subscriptions in IR.